# real_escape_string on multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm trying to escape values from a multidimensional array for my database class. The code I have currently:

```
// Function to escape array values
private function esc_sql_arr(array $to_esc) {
    $clean_arr = array();
    foreach($to_esc as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($to_esc[$k])) {
            foreach($to_esc[$k] as $key => $val) {
                $k = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($k);
                $key = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($key);
                $val = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($val);
                $clean_arr[$k][$key] = $val;
            }
        } else {
            $k = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($k);
            $v = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($v);
            $clean_arr[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $clean_arr;
}
```

I'm assuming the following input example (it should be 'where', I purposely changed it to test the above method):

```
$args = array(
    "table" => "t'1",
    "data"  => array(
                "c'sf4;(" => 'xdfbxdrf',
                'c2' => "'t'est'",
                'cs' => 'hey'
                ),
    "whe're" => array(
                'test' => 'test1'
                )
    );
```

var_dump:

```
array (size=3)
  'table' => string 't\'1' (length=4)
  'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'c\'sf4;(' => string 'xdfbxdrf' (length=8)
      'c2' => string '\'t\'est\'' (length=10)
      'cs' => string 'hey' (length=3)
  'whe\'re' => 
    array (size=1)
      'test' => string 'test1' (length=5)
```

The code works without any issue. However, is this the right way to escape a multidimensional array?

I believe I might not have to use this method since I use prepared statements. Any feedback on using this is welcome.

Comment: How do you insert a multi-dimensional array into the database in the first place? At some point you have to reduce it do a flat value, and that's the point where you use prepared statements (or if for whatever reason you insist on escaping, that's where you escape). I don't see any point in recursively escaping an entire array.

Comment: @deceze I guess I didn't put it correctly in the OP. The only part that goes into the database is `data`. Basically, I'm running a couple of functions to separate table, data and further inputs (where etc)  and then generate the query based on that. I should probably escape it at a later time now that I think about it.

Comment: Yes indeed, you should.